# How to submit a file to AWS Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, file, aws-lambda

I have the following architecture:
(1) A front-end form, which has a user input of file:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('username', 'USER123');
data.append('file', selectedFile); //selectedFile is a file which I capture form a form (user-submitted)
await fetch('myURL/test', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  body:data
}).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json))
console.log('Done')
```

(2) An AWS API Gateway (which has a POST route of 'myURL/test'),
(3) An AWS Lambda Integration with the following Python Code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context): #Lambda functions works and returns a response of "Hello from Lambda" during a POST request
    # TODO implement
    print(event['body']) //prints some base64 string
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve: User submits form (with .zip file) from my front-end, (2) Lambda function receives the file, (3) Lambda function checks whether file is correct size, type, (4) Lambda function uploads file to S3 Bucket. The thing is I am unable to receive the file in my lambda function. Printing of the event['body'] prints out some weird string that I'm unsure on how to process.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you have a limit on how big the file uploaded can be? Are you limiting anything else regarding this file upload?

Comment: The files can be quite large, I do have some files going up to 25 MB. I think my other approach is to use Pre-Signed URLs but I was curious if I could go directly from the API gateway/Lambda

Comment: I want to clarifying because I think API have a limit for payload or files upload.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the Incoming Request at the Gateway is actually passing the POST body content (the file) to the Lambda. Likely you'll need to setup a mapping template along these lines...
`{ "content": "$input.body" }`

Here's a pretty good article showing the end-to-end setup to upload a file:
https://medium.com/swlh/upload-binary-files-to-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-with-aws-lambda-2b4ba8c70b8e

Comment: The thing is I did connect it as a trigger to API Gateway, so this should happen automatically. I am passing in two variables from the front-end, `username` and `file`, but whenever I do a print(event['body']), it prints out a random string (I'm sure this is base64 encoded or something but I am so unsure why or how to move from here